# In MySQL SELECT queries with COUNT, what values are populated for non-aggregate columns?

Tags: mysql, count

In the statement

```
select count(*), foo from bar;
```

if my database table has many rows, and all have different values of 'foo', how does MySQL select the value to display in the result:

```
+----------+-----------+
| count(*) | foo       |
+----------+-----------+
|       30 | baz       |
+----------+-----------+
```

I'm assuming it's officially 'undefined' but I can't find this described anywhere in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: is `bazz` last or first record according the primary key?

Comment: You should not use such a query in the first place because it is against the sql standard and may not run in mysq depending on its configuration.

Comment: Thanks Shadow - I realise this is not a very useful kind of query. Where does is say in the MySQL documentation that this is against the SQL standard?

Answer (score 1):

It takes the first item by default. It's the same thing if you do group by -  it just takes the first entry for each group.